# Getting AWS Availability Zone saved in bash script variable

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services

Using a shell script, I'm looking to get the current AZ where the instance is located.

Here is what I've tried but obviously HOST_NAME is not a command. How do I save the current AZ in a HOST_NAME variable?

```
AZ=`ec2-metadata -z | cut -d':' -f2` 

if [[ $AZ = "eu-west-2a" ]]
then
  HOST_NAME = "es_az1"
elif [[ $AZ = "eu-west-2b" ]]
then
  HOST_NAME = "es_az2"
else
  HOST_NAME = "es_az3"
  exit 1;
fi
```

Comment: cut-n-paste your script (along with appropriate shebang) into [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net/), make the suggested changes, and if you're still having problems then come back and update the question with a) up-to-date code you've tried, b) a description of the (wrong) output/behavior of your script, and c) the (correct) expected output/behavior of your script; it would also be a good idea to .... after the `AZ=` and before the `if` block add `typeset -p AZ` ... and update the question with the output from the `typeset -p` call so we can see what's in the variable `AZ`

Comment: Is the HOST_NAME variable for use solely within this shell script, or are you trying to persist it into the shell that this script was run from, or into the user's login script so that it persists across logins? At the very least, remove the spacing, so: `HOST_NAME="es_az1"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have **spaces** in `HOST_NAME =` . It should eb:

```
AZ=`ec2-metadata -z | cut -d':' -f2` 

if [[ $AZ = "eu-west-2a" ]]
then
  HOST_NAME="es_az1"
elif [[ $AZ = "eu-west-2b" ]]
then
  HOST_NAME="es_az2"
else
  HOST_NAME="es_az3"
  exit 1;
fi
```